# Shift-Option-<key> is adding accented characters

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization

On El Capitan (10.11.4) I somehow got into a state where using the key combination <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> outputs accented or special characters.  For example

> <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> : 
>
> <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> : Ô

I have those key combos mapped to some useful commands in my text editor (RubyMine/IntelliJ), but instead of those commands working, I now just get the special character input.  I assume it must be a built in OS X option (I've tried various keyboards) but I can't find any way to disable it.   Any ideas?

Comment: Since option and option plus shift are always used by Apple for special characters by default, it's normally best to use control and command for shortcuts.  Perhaps the Karabiner app can override that.

Comment: It turns out that you need to create a custom keylayout in order to disable this.  I followed the steps here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876485/how-to-disable-typing-special-characters-when-pressing-option-key-in-mac-os-x/24100077#24100077

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid accented characters you need to create and use a custom keylayout file.  I followed the steps outlined here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876485/how-to-disable-typing-special-characters-when-pressing-option-key-in-mac-os-x/24100077#24100077